# Syntax highlighting for C++ code, initializing with `()` vs `=`

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I had initially asked this on [Code review meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10565/syntax-highlighting-for-c-initializing-with-vs) but @Mast in the comments suggested me to ask this on the main meta site.

I have tested it on Stack overflow, Code review, and Software Engineering sites. I think stack exchange uses the same syntax highlighting engine so it should apply to all

### Question

Here is the example

```
int a = 5;
int c(5);
```

I hope the syntax highlighting works for you, if not then the way `a` and `c` are highlighted is different, shouldn't they be highlighted the same way?

`c` has the same highlighting as a function would have (bright orange)
whereas `a` has no highlight.

[image: highlight]

Comment: @MartijnPieters How does that answer this question?

Comment: Sorry, was interrupted: please file bugs in the highlighter with the highlight.js project, as mentioned in that FAQ under the heading *How do I report a bug or request a new language?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), if only because syntax highlighting is not running off of a full parser for all languages, but rather a basic parser and parsing `int c(5);` as a method declaration seems ... plausible for that kind of parser.

Comment: Correct. It’s being matched as a function declaration. Pretty sure there’s an open issue for this too, but hard to fix.